# On a conjecture about the arithmetic function that counts the number of twin primes

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-constellations, prime-gaps

This is cross-posted from the question that I've [asked with same title on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3593090/on-a-conjecture-about-the-arithmetic-function-that-counts-the-number-of-twin-pri) two months ago, which has remained unanswered.

Given a positive real number $x$ we will write positive integer or real number $x$) as $$\pi_2(x)=\#\{\text{ primes }p\leq x\,:\,p+2\text{ is also a prime}\}$$
the arithmetic function that counts the number of primes $p$ less than a given positive real $x$ satisfying that $p+2$ is also a prime. (Such primes are known as [twin primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime). It is an open problem if there are infinitely many twin primes. Inspired by the [Second Hardy–Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture), a few experiments using Pari/GP scripts to state the following two conjectures.

**Conjecture 1.** *One has* $$\pi_2(x+y)\leq \pi_2(x)+\pi_2(y)+1$$
*for all integer* $x\geq 2$ *and all integer* $y\geq 2$.

**Conjecture 2.** *There exists an integer constant* $K\geq 2$ *such that* $$\pi_2(x+y)\leq \pi_2(x)+\pi_2(y)+1$$
*holds, for all integer* $x\geq K$ *and all integer* $y\geq K$.

> **Question.** Are these known, or is it possible to prove or refute any of previous conjectures? Can you find counterexamples for the first conjecture or add heuristics to know what about the veracity of this kind of conjectures?

I've tested the first conjecture for the segments of integers $2\leq x,y\leq 500$. I've added the second conjecture since I don't know if it is possible to find easily a counterexample for **Conjecture 1.**

**Edit:** Additionally/alternatively you can investigate **what work can be done for/what about the veracity of** the conjectures on assumption that the twin prime conjecture holds, or under assumption of other well-known conjectures. If this question is hard, I should to accept an answer that provide the more helpful discussion about what work can be done for our questions currently. See the contributions in comments of the users of the linked MSE post.

### References:

[1] G. H. Hardy and J. E. Littlewood, *Some Problems of 'Partitio Numerorum.' III. On the Expression of a Number as a Sum of Primes*, Acta Math. (44),  J. E. (1923) pp. 1–70.

Comment: In the unlikely event that the Twin Prime Conjecture is false, then of course both conjectures here are true for sufficiently large $x,y$ since we'll have $\pi_2(x+y)=\pi_2(x)=\pi_2(y)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your clarification and help, then I'm going to delete the question in next minures @GerryMyerson

Comment: I've undelete the post @GerryMyerson in case that there is more feedback (notice that I know about your excellent knowledges but I believe that I deleted my post abruptly , just as my decission). Thus I'm sorry and thanks for your patience, I hope that there is more feedback in next few days, many thanks again for your attention.

Comment: I'm glad you undeleted. My comment did not at all completely resolve your question. Please don't consider my comment as grounds for deleting your question.

Comment: The most interesting thing to do is to study this conjecture under the condition of the first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture. One could try to show that conjecture 1 is false under that assumption by the same strategy as the second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture - i.e. by finding an admissible tuple which contains too many twin pairs. This should be more fruitful to perform a computer search on than looking at twin primes directly.

Comment: Many thanks @WillSawin for your attention and help, also thanks again for previous professor in comments. I'm not a professional mathematician but I understand many of the details of the answers that provide the professors here for my questions, thus feel free to add your thoughts as an answer since these are according the **Question** and my previous **Edit** (that one can to invoke conjectures, heuristics or other reasonings to provide an answer).

Comment: Many thanks for the edit professor @JoshuaZ

Comment: Many thanks for your edit @kodlu